# I want to make a one-to-one relationship between two columns in ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have `reading` and `jobOrder` class. I want to create a relationship between `joborderId` in the `jobOrder` class and `jobOrderId` in `reading` class.

```
public class JobOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int JobOrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }

    public string MachineCode { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalLength { get; set; }
}

public class Reading
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MachineCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Length { get; set; }
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; }

    public int JobOrderId { get; set; }
    public JobOrder JobOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: are the `Id` and `JobOrderId` in `JobOrder` class different things?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to take a look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#one-to-one

If you do it the way you described then EF will choose one of the entities to be the dependent based on its ability to detect a foreign key property. If the wrong entity is chosen as the dependent, you can use the Fluent API to correct this.

When configuring the relationship with the Fluent API, you use the HasOne and WithOne methods.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasOne(p => p.BlogImage)
        .WithOne(i => i.Blog)
        .HasForeignKey<BlogImage>(b => b.BlogForeignKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [code first naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in) EF will automatically discover the Key, ForeignKey and Navigation properties :

```cs
public class JobOrder
{
    // Primary key (can be JobOrderId as well)
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other fields...

    // Foreign key
    public int ReadingId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public Reading Reading { get; set; }
}

public class Reading
{
    // Primary key (can be ReadingId as well)
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other fields...

    // Foreign key
    public int JobOrderId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public JobOrder JobOrder { get; set; }
}
```

If you have more than one key [*composite keys*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#composite-keys) to create the relationship, you need to manually define the keys and foreign keys:

```cs
public class JobOrder
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order=2)]
    public int JobOrderNo { get; set; }


    // other fields...

    // Foreign key
    public int ReadingId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public Reading Reading { get; set; }
}

public class Reading
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other fields...

    [ForeignKey("JobOrder")]
    [Column(Order=1)]
    public int JobOrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("JobOrder")]
    [Column(Order=2)]
    public int JobOrderNo { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public JobOrder JobOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about going like this, it will create 1 to 1 relationship between JobOrder and Reading

```
public class JobOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int JobOrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }

    public string MachineCode { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalLength { get; set; }

    public virtual Reading Reading { get; set; }
}

public class Reading
{
    [Key]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("JobOrder")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MachineCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Length { get; set; }
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; }

    public JobOrder JobOrder { get; set; }
}
```